# Making air pollution model in QGIS

Tags: qgis, model, air-quality, gaussian-plume

I'm writing a bachelor thesis about air pollution from point source and I want, to put it to GIS, but I don't know really how...

I'm working with Gaussian plume model, so I have pollution concentration in distance from the source. What else do I need to make GIS pollution model, if I have concentration in distance from source?

I want to make something like this http://ready.arl.noaa.gov/gaussian-bin/usrdisp2.pl in QGIS

I have installed QGIS 2.4, this is my first experience with GIS.

Comment: I found a paper that you might want to read for additional research.  There might be methods in there that are helpful.  Doing a quick Google of *Gaussian plume model qgis* came up with this article talking about something similar: http://hal.cirad.fr/docs/00/46/88/63/PDF/MO2009-PUB00026817.pdf

Comment: Ive read it and downloaded data and make layer from OSM. What next ? make raster with my concentration data ? O should I try make digital terrain model ? Ive just read too much and have a little mess in it

Comment: I think your question still needs to be narrowed down further. Are you just trying to display the pollution plume on a map? (Look into [ALOHA](http://response.restoration.noaa.gov/aloha) which makes plumes and [can be imported into QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50813/how-can-i-import-aloha-pas-plume-file-into-qgis) with some tweaking.) Are you trying to actually make a software model that generates a plume? Neither a concentration raster nor an elevation model sound like useful components in either case.

Comment: sorry i wasnt here. I want to make this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHhE0yJtJqg 
but only for one city. I downloaded data from OSM ( polygons ) and save them like shp. Than in R i add my files but it dispaly error message